# Cluster items based on similarity

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, similarity, cosine-similarity, dbscan

I'm quite new to the whole clustering and stuff, so I'm a bit lost in the final bit of programming.
After doing some bits already to get the right similarity between Item and the Items_Comp. I have an example dataset of the following (The Value belongs to the Items column):

```
Items Items_Comp Similarity Item Value
A  B  0.6  50
A  C  0.0  50
A  D  0.0  50
A  E  0.2  50
B  A  0.6  100
B  C  0.2  100
B  D  0.4  100
B  E  0.4  100
C  A  0.0  200
C  B  0.2  200
C  D  0.6  200
C  E  0.6  200
...
```

Want I want now is to cluster all of them together based on the similarity, if the similarity is >=0.6 they should be clustered together and the cluster should be named after the item with the highest item value:

So like:

```
Group  Items 
B  A
B  B
C  C
C  D
C  E
...
```

How would the the best way to create such a dataframe in python? Should I use DBSCAN, as I don't know the amount of clusters, and how would I incorporate the similarity in DBSCAN?

Best,
Luke

Comment: This may work: `cluster1 = dataset[dataset['Similarity']>=0.6]`, `cluster2 = dataset[dataset['Similarity']<0.6]`.

Answer (score 0):

DBSCAN is a density clustering method when you haven't circular clusters. If you only want to sort the datas with a rule (similarity < 0.6) you don't need this kind of algorithm. However if you want to find a rule or new clusters that you didn't expect you may first try classic algorithms like K-means or CAH and then try DBSCAN.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).